# How to can I count the number of ones?

Tags: matlab

The problem is:
In a class of 26 students, a test with 10 questions is given. The students answer the question by tossing a coin. I have to find out how many students have two or less answers correct. This is the program that I wrote, but I'm  not sure about it ... is it good?

```
correct=0;
students=0;
for i=1:26
    for j=1:10
        answ=ceil(rand);
        if answ==1
            correct=correct+1;
            if correct==2
                students=students+1;
            end
        end
    end
end
disp(students)
```

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: For the record, this is actually a pre-defined function. y = `binocdf(10,26,0.5)` http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binocdf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight modification to your code:

```
correct=0;
students=0;
for i=1:26
    for j=1:10
        answ=round(rand);    % Use round instead of ceil
        if (answ==1)
          correct=correct+1;
          if correct==2
              students=students+1;
              break;
          end
        end
    end
    correct=0;   % Was missing in original code
end
disp(students)
```

**Additional Note:**

1. Try testing code for correct ans 5 as this will have more chances of variation to result because of uniform distribution of random number. Most of the students will get at-least 2 correct ans assuming equal probability, which is not the practical case.
2. Try maintaining habit of proper indentation. It will be more readable and less prone to errors.

Answer (score 5):

It's neater, faster to run, and more readable if you do it **vectorized**:

```
answers = round(rand(10,26)); % 10x26 matrix of 0 / 1 values
correct = sum(answers); % sum along each column
students = sum(correct<=2) % how many values of correct are 2 or less
```

By the way, from your code it appears you want to know how many students have 2 or *more* correct answers (not 2 or *less* as you state). In that case change last line to

```
students = sum(correct>=2) % how many values of correct are 2 or more
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this : (You have to reset correct counter for every student, and some `end` aren't at the right place.)

```
correct = 0;
students = 0;

for i = 1:26
  for j = 1:10
    answ = ceil(rand);
    if(answ==1)
      correct = correct + 1;
    end
  end

  if(correct < 2)
    students = students + 1;
  end

  correct= 0;
end
```

**EdIT**

Sorry, I didn't saw the less in your sentense, so I change the `>` for `<`